# Automata accepting

Tags: automata

Let $A = \{ a,b\} $ and $ L = \{ w \in A^* : |a| = 2k+1, |b| = 2l, k,l \ge 0 \}$

$|a| = 2k+1 $ means that amount of 'a' in word $w$  should be odd. 
I am asking for any advice.
I tried do it a lot of hours.

Comment: Please provide more context. Are you looking for an automata that recognises $L$? Should it be a DFA or NFA or something else? If you've tried for lots of hours, then what have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: It may be DFA or NFA or regular expression. I deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

To keep track of, if there is an odd number of $a$ symbols, you need only two states, one corresponding to "odd number of $a$ seen so far" $q_{oa}$ and one corresponding to "even number of $a$ seen so far" $q_{ea}$ and every accepted $a$ should switch between those two states.

Similar construction for $b$. Combine this into a product of states
$$
Q = \{ q_{eaeb}, q_{oaeb}, q_{eaob}, q_{oaob} \}
$$
Initially you are in state $q_0 = q_{eaeb}$ and $q_{oaeb}$ should be the final state, $F = \{ q_{oaeb} \}$.

Then we have the transitions
$$
\begin{array}{cc|c}
q & s & q' = \delta(q, s) \\
\hline
q_{eaeb} & a & q_{oaeb} \\
q_{eaeb} & b & q_{eaob} \\
q_{eaob} & a & q_{oaob} \\
q_{eaob} & b & q_{eaeb} \\
q_{oaeb} & a & q_{eaeb} \\
q_{oaeb} & b & q_{oaob} \\
q_{oaob} & a & q_{eaob} \\
q_{oaob} & b & q_{oaeb} \\
\end{array}
$$

This should specify the DFA $\mathcal{A} = (Q, A, q_0, \delta, F)$.

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$
[image: graph A]